# docker commit does not include manually copied file inside the container

Tags: java, docker

I need to manually include an external jar into the classpath of a java application running inside a docker container. I am providing this external jar using `docker cp` command. But the moment I restart the container, the external jar vanishes. I read that I can make it persist using `docker commit` but even with that the external jar is missing in the new container. Below are the steps I performed:

1. Pull the image `apache/nifi:latest` and start the container.
2. Copy the external jar into the classpath of the nifi application inside container.

   ```
    docker cp C:\logstash-logback-encoder-6.6.jar f603e68c8888:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.12.1.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
   ```
3. Check the file was copied correctly.

   ```
    nifi@f603e68c8888:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.12.1.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib$ ls
    logstash-logback-encoder-6.6.jar  nifi-metrics-1.12.1.jar           simpleclient_common-0.3.0.jar
    metrics-core-4.1.2.jar            nifi-prometheus-utils-1.12.1.jar  simpleclient_hotspot-0.3.0.jar
    metrics-jvm-4.1.2.jar             simpleclient-0.3.0.jar            simpleclient_servlet-0.3.0.jar
   ```
4. With this container running, from another terminal commit the current container state into new image. (Also tried with exiting the terminal without stopping the container and then commiting)

   ```
    docker commit f603e68c8888 nifinew
   ```
5. Create new container from this new image.

   ```
    docker run nifinew
   ```
6. Check the classpath location in the container for the external jar.

   ```
    nifi@b486c68c9274:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.12.1.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib$ ls
    metrics-core-4.1.2.jar  nifi-metrics-1.12.1.jar           simpleclient-0.3.0.jar         simpleclient_hotspot-0.3.0.jar
    metrics-jvm-4.1.2.jar   nifi-prometheus-utils-1.12.1.jar  simpleclient_common-0.3.0.jar  simpleclient_servlet-0.3.0.jar
   ```

The external jar remains missing in the new container. I also noticed through `docker inspect` the container uses volumes for below locations but that's not where I am copying my file inside the container. So `docker commit` should have included the file with the commit.

```
    "Volumes": {
            "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf": {},
            "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository": {},
            "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository": {},
            "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository": {},
            "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs": {},
            "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository": {},
            "/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state": {}
        },
```

**EDIT:**
I tried with below Dockerfile as well which didn't work. I still don't see the jar at the COPY location in the new container.

```
    FROM apache/nifi:latest
    COPY logstash-logback-encoder-6.6.jar /opt/nifi/nifi-current/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.12.1.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
```

Comment: Instead of committing the docker image create a simple docker file with `COPY` command to copy the required library to the path and build the image. Also you haven't provided the tag while committing the image. By default it is tagged `latest` which might be used by the running container therefore try tagging it with some custom tag.

Comment: `docker commit` never includes content in mounted volumes, which is why you're not seeing it in the produced image.  Using `docker commit` at all is rarely a best practice, though; it leads to unreproducible one-off images.  Follow @Faisal's suggestion to `docker build` the image with a simple Dockerfile, committed to source control.

Comment: @DavidMaze I specifically said that I did NOT copy the file to a mounted volume. The snippet showing "Volumes" is there to prove that it does not have the path where I am copying the jar inside the container.

Comment: @Faisal The image that I pulled is already of tag ```latest``` as you can see in the point #1. So it should not matter in this case

Comment: @Faisal Tried the Dockerfile as well which didn't work. Updated the description

Comment: The dockerfile approach is your best bet at making this work. Is the file in your build context when you do the build? Can you show us the output of such a build (you'll have to touch the file to make the build re-run if its cached). To reiterate what others have said, you should not be trying this manually -- it's a bad approach.

Comment: what command are you using for the build and did it throw any error while running the `COPY` command please check you might need to use `root` user for copying the file in that directory depending on the permissions of the folder in which you are copying the file.

Comment: @Faisal ```docker build -t nifiimg .``` and no errors